# How effective are praying mantis in keeping a garden clear of pests?

Tags: pest-control, insects, bugs

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with using praying mantises for pest control, and what kinds of pests could be managed with them?

Comment: I have tons of them here. They are wild, not introduced. They eat mostly locusts, bees, moths etc I think. Haven't needed to use them as pest control (I don't have big pest problems here anymore).

Comment: Start with the problem and work backwards.  What pests do you want to control?

Comment: I have none but am curious about the potential benefit(s) from an intellectual perspective.

Comment: I think generally predatory insects will reduce a pest problem but not remove it completely - the predator needs to be able to survive as well, and if it completely wiped out it's food its children would have nothing to eat next year.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mantids are not spectacular for pest control because they're very indiscriminate in choosing their prey. They readily attack other beneficial insects as well as harmful or pest insects.

I always get a few each year, usually around something that is blooming. In my area, they like to sit and wait for pollinators.

They like to attack larger prey and tend to stay away from the tiny insects like whiteflies or aphids. If you're looking for a good pest control solution for smaller insects like those, green lacewing larvae are an excellent choice (not ladybugs!).

If you have a cucumber beetle, Japanese beetle, squash vine borer, or squash bug problem, mantids may be beneficial for you, especially as these pests are often resistant to pesticides.

Comment: Every year I get a mantid living on my nepeta. It gets fat snagging bumble-bees throughout the summer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not Ladybugs? In my experience they're hell on wheels against aphids.

Comment: Ladybugs themselves are not great predators of aphids. Yes they do consume some, but by and large they are most effective in the larval stage. That's all well and good if your ladybugs stick around to reproduce. Ladybugs are unfortunately migratory by nature and tend not to stay where you put them. It's typically more effective to stick with something that's not going to fly away on you the instant you release them.

Answer (score 2):

They are best utilized when purchased young as they will grow up eating small things and will eat larger things eventually as the grow. It is important to space them out when they are young as they tend to resort to cannibalism if left hungry for too long.

Some kinds of mantis will actually roam around hunting prey rather than waiting to ambush it.

> **Pest control uses**
>
> Organic gardeners who avoid pesticides may encourage mantises as a
> form of biological pest control. During fall in temperate regions,
> mantis females typically deposit an ootheca on the underside of a leaf
> or on a twig, and in some species these are harvested commercially. If
> the egg case survives winter, the offspring, called nymphs, emerge in
> late spring or early summer. The nymphs have voracious appetites and
> typically cannibalize each other if they cannot find an adequate
> supply of aphids and other small insects. Tens of thousands of mantis
> egg cases are sold each year in some garden stores for this purpose.
> However, mantises prey on neutral and beneficial insects as well,
> basically eating anything they can successfully capture and devour. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis))
>
> **Diet changes over lifetime**
>
> Insects form their primary prey, but the diet of a mantis changes as
> it grows larger. In its first instar a mantis eats small insects such
> as tiny flies or its own siblings. In later instars it does not or
> cannot profitably pursue such small prey. In the final instar as a
> rule the diet still includes more insects than anything else, but
> large species of mantis have been known to prey on small scorpions,
> lizards, frogs, birds, snakes, fish, and even rodents; they feed on
> any species small enough for them to capture, but large enough to
> engage their attention. For example, a large mantis feeding on a bee
> or bug might be pestered with impunity by jackal flies and biting
> midges that it would readily have eaten in its first instar. Large
> prey tends to increase in value with the cube of its size: a blowfly
> four times as long as a jackal fly represents a meal about 64 times as
> massive. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis))